# Android Studio/IntelliJ - Curly braces doesn't go to new line even with proper settings

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

In Editor > Code Style > Java, I currently have my Braces placement settings to "Next Line" for In class declaration, In method declaration, and Other. Yet when I create a new method and press Enter between the two braces: { `<here>` }, the closing brace gets properly formatted but the opening brace still stay on the same line as the method declaration, like so:

```
public void Test() {

}
```

but I want it to auto format to this instead:

```
public void Test()
{

}
```

Am I missing a setting that I should change? If it matters any, I'm using Android Studio 2.3.3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `Editor > Code Style > Java > Wrapping and Braces` go to:

- `Braces placement`

  - `In method declaration: Next line`

Here's an example screenshot:

[image]

IntelliJ will leave the opening brace on the same line when you hit `ENTER` but if you reformat that class then IntelliJ will apply your chosen format resulting in the opening brace being moved onto the next line. You can reformat your code from the menu: `Code > Reformat Code` or have a look at `Preferences > Keymap > Main Menu > Code > Reformat Code` to see the keystroke combination for applying the formatter.

Comment: I have already set everything under Braces placement to "Next line" but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe IntelliJ is telling you not to use that ugly .NET/C# convention.

Comment: @RichardHolmes IntelliJ will leave the opening brace on the same line when you hit `ENTER` but if you reformat that class (`Code > Reformat Code`) then IntelliJ will apply your chosen format resulting in the opening brace being moved onto the next line.

Comment: @glitch It does not auto-format? Is there no option for that?

Comment: No, your file will not be auto formatted on hitting `ENTER` inside a braces-pair. `Preferences > Keymap > Main Menu > Code > Reformat Code` will show you the keystroke combination for applying the formatter.

Comment: @glitch Thanks! I think you should update your post to contain your comments here.

Comment: For Kotlin, `Braces Placement -> Put left brace on new line` seems to work. I had to use the auto format shortcut to apply the convention though (CTRL+ALT+L on Windows or Command+Option+L on Mac).

Answer (score -1):

apparently some one at Google decided to act like Microsoft and try to force their opinion on the rest of us and disabled the ability to reformat the coed (almost) at all,

check their FAQ regarding Dart formatter at: https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style/wiki/FAQ

[image: Can't format Dart]

i suggest using a different IDE (funny enough like MS Visual Studio Code)

I always thought that the IDE's responsibility is to allow each person style his/hers code the way their brain can process it easily and fast recognize the code parts (hence styling and coloring code),

a nice feature would be the ability to see the code in the IDE the way we like it, but when saved to git - reformated to a general / company standarts, and when the code is loaded from the git it should be auto reformat to the way my IDE is set to display it

uniqueness and diversity should be celebrated and not forced into darker days rules where we are all the same